# How do I add the format for underlining text in xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Just want to know how to create a variable for underlining text in the package xlsxwriter. For example, this is the one I created for making it bold:

```
bold_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
```

Sorry if the answer is blatantly obvious, I tried looking it up to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below mentioned code to achieve underline

```
underline_format = workbook.add_format({'underline': True})
```

in addition you can check this [link](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html) for more formatting options

Answer (score -1):

You can specify several different cell formats in the dictionary:

```py
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red', 'num_format': '$#,##0.00',})
worksheet.write('A1', 'Cell A1', cell_format)

# Later...
cell_format.set_font_color('green')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Cell B1', cell_format)
```